# Retrieving the ID of many-side objects in a many-to-one relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

Let's say I have two classes, Parent and Child.  These two are related via a uni-directional relationship.

```
<bag name="children" cascade="all">
    <key column="parent_id" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
</bag>
```

If I want to add a child element to the parent, as far as I know I need to load the parent, add a child to it, and save the parent:

```
Parent p = dao.getParent();
Child c = new Child();
p.getChildren().add(c);
dao.saveOrUpdate(p);
```

However, a problem arises when trying to mirror this change in the data model backing the GUI.  As far as I can tell, there's no way of finding the primary key that was assigned to `c` when it was persisted.  This is causing a problem in the GUI, for if I add multiple rows to the model it's impossible to distinguish them for later use.

Any ideas how I might be able to access the child's primary key after it's been persisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access autogenerated keys after the session is flushed, i.e. either after an explcit `session.flush()` or after transaction commit.

Comment: Huh... I could have sworn I checked that and it was coming back as null.  But I just debugged and you're right.  Thanks.